# access last if-statement-condition result value

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

```
var check = someCheck();
if (check){
  doOne(check);
}else{
  doTwo();
}
```

Can I be able to write the same code without defining check var? something like this below

```
if (someCheck()){
  doOne(<magic-value-passed-which-is-result-of_someCheck()>);
}else{
  doTwo();
}
```

Note that check could be a true, or any object or null or undefined, what all a function call could return.

I am thinking of the following solution as

```
var condition;
function setCondition(stmt){
  condition = stmt;
}

if ( setCondition(someCheck()) ){
  doOne(condition)
}else{
  doTwo();
}
```

still am not much happy with this one, as `setCondition` is a lengthy name, wanna write simple and less code. Can we teak `if` itself or similar like any idea where could we access last `if` checked value? is `if` a function here?

Comment: You can always try to make a recursive function.

Comment: Do you have an example of another language (besides JavaScript) that does do something like this? (for context)

Comment: It is not possible in javascript

Comment: @DavinTryon sorry, no example I have, I found this pattern in my code a lot of times hence checking. I could actually define my own function to replace with if loop like I will name it as doIf(condition, ifBlock, elseBlock) :)

Comment: try this `if (check = someCheck()){}`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, something similar is possible indeed in C-like languages (such as JavaScript):

```
if (check = someCheck()) { ... } // 'check' should be already defined
```

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap the part in an IIFE.

ES6

```
(v => v ? doOne(v) : doTwo())(someCheck());
```

ES5

```
void function (v) { v ? doOne(v) : doTwo(); }(someCheck());
```